# Add a body class for product category archive page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, hook-wordpress

I want to add product category slug in the body class on product category archive pages.

Here is an example of what I would like *(url of the product category page example)*: 
`https://example.com/product-category/canon/`… So I would like **"canon"** in the body class.

Answer (score 2):

Your example link doesn't seem to work; however, WooCommerce should already be adding a term-specific class to your category pages: something along the lines of `archive tax-product_cat term-{slug} term-{id}` to a product category page. Taking your example link, and assuming the term ID is `7` (for example), the body class would include:

```
tax-product_cat term-7 term-canon
```

So if you need to access it via CSS/jQuery/whatever, you can use the selector `body.term-canon`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use page slug in body class, See this code

```
function add_slug_body_class( $classes ) {
global $post;
if ( isset( $post ) ) {
$classes[] = $post->post_type . '-' . $post->post_name;
}
return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_slug_body_class' );
```

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to add the below code in your functions.php file in your activated theme.

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'product_cats_css_body_class' );

function product_cats_css_body_class( $classes ){
  if( is_archive( 'product-cat' ) )
  {
    $custom_terms = get_the_terms(0, 'product_cat');
    if ($custom_terms) {
      foreach ($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
        $classes[] = $custom_term->slug;
      }
    }
  }
  return $classes;
}
```

this will add the category slug at the last of body class.

Answer (score 0):

Even if Woocommerce **embed as body class the product category term slug as `term-canon`**, you can **easily add just `canon`** using the dedicated WordPress [`body_class`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/body_class) action hook, with Woocommerce [`is_product_category()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-5) conditional function and WordPress [`get_queried_object()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) this way:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'product_category_slug_to_body_class', 99, 1 );
function product_category_slug_to_body_class( $classes ){
    if( is_product_category() ){
        $classes[] = get_queried_object()->slug;
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.