# Add a body class for top level product categories to WooCommerce archives

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

I am using WooCommerce and have product categories, subcategories and sub-subcategories. I need to apply some css ONLY to the product categories that are not a subcategory (the main "parent" product categories). Is there any body selector for these?

So far I have only come up with the solution to use each category's ID but this results in a ton of css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on *[Add a body class for product category archive page in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52163281/add-a-body-class-for-product-category-archive-page-in-woocommerce/52169211#52169211)* answer code, using the dedicated WordPress [`body_class`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/body_class) action hook, with Woocommerce [`is_product_category()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-5), you can add `top-category` as body class for all your top level category archive pages with the following:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'parent_category_as_body_class', 99, 1 );
function parent_category_as_body_class( $classes ){
    if( is_product_category() ){
        $ancestors = get_ancestors( get_queried_object_id(), 'product_cat' );

        if( count($ancestors) == 0 ) $classes[] = 'top-category';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

- [Wordpress `get_queried_object_id()` documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object_id)
- [Wordpress `get_ancestors()` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_ancestors/)